# format powershell output to like table format

Tags: sharepoint, powershell

I have this code below and I would like to display the output in a table like fashion

```
$spSite = Get-SPSite "http://sp2010" 
$spWeb = $spSite.OpenWeb()

$spList = $spWeb.Lists["ReportList"]
$items = $spList.Items
foreach($item in $items)
{
    Write-Host  $item["ID"] $item["Name"] $item["Department"] $item["Telephone"]

}
```

like this:

```
ID      Name            Department        Telephone
---    --------         -----------       ------------

1       Somone          IT                 02554445588
```

I saw Format-Table, but I cannot seem to get the hang of it.

Some example using the code above will be very much appreciated.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hard to even start helping, because current code simply won't work... ($spListItem is... what? foreach uses $item, can we assume you are using it?). Also: we have very little to no information about type of this items, it looks like some dictionary object... Anyway, I would try:

```
$items | ForEach-Object {
    # assume $items is array of dictionary objects...
    New-Object PSObject -Property $_
} | Format-Table ID, Name, Department, Telephone
```

obviously, it may not work, because I made some assumptions that can be just wrong.. ;)

Comment: Hi BartekB, thanks for the remark. I just changed the code. This propably will be clearer.

Answer (score -1):

Give this a try:

```
function Get-SPListItem
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true)] 
        [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPList]$List,

        [Parameter()] 
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$ViewName
    )

    process 
    {
        try
        {
            if($PSCmdlet.MyInvocation.BoundParameters.ContainsKey('ViewName'))
            { 
                $views = $list.Views | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Title   

                if($views -contains $ViewName)        
                {
                    $columns = $List.Views[$ViewName].ViewFields
                }
                else
                {
                    throw 'Invalid view name'
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                $columns = $List.DefaultView.ViewFields
            }

            foreach($item in $List.Items) 
            {
                $obj = New-Object PSObject

                foreach($col in $columns) 
                {
                    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $col -Value $item[$col]
                }

                $obj
            }

        } 
        catch
        {
            Write-Error $_
        }    
    }
}


$spWeb.Lists["ReportList"] | Get-SPListItem
```